# jQuery -prototype conflict

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I am using a combination of prototype and script.aculo.us to implement a lightbox effect in my asp.net page.I have also jquery included in my page.I have several DIV tags in my page,But after including the prototype file in my head of the page,I am not able to read the divs in my javascript using jquery

```
var div = $("#divLeftSideModelsList"); 
alert(div)
```

gives me an error saying that the object is null
But

```
var div = document.getElementById("divLeftSideModelsList")
```

is giving me the object.

Is this becuase there is some conflicts between jQuery and other frameworks ?

PLEASE advice

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? Would you like any further help on it or can you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a read of this: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Shows good examples :)

**OVERRIDING THE $-FUNCTION**

However, you can override that default by calling jQuery.noConflict() at any point after jQuery and the other library have both loaded. For example:

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

This will revert $ back to its original library. You'll still be able to use "jQuery" in the rest of your application.

Additionally, there's another option. If you want to make sure that jQuery won't conflict with another library - but you want the benefit of a short name, you could do something like this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via $j(...)
     $j(document).ready(function(){
       $j("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use jQuery in [noConflict mode](http://sdf). And then use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange bug. Anyways, both prototype and jQuery redefine the global variable $.

Please read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) to know how jQuery can play nice with other libraries.

It basically says that calling jQuery.noConflict() leaves the $ variable alone for the other libs to use

Answer (score -2):

Does this code work:

```
var div = jQuery("#divLeftSideModelsList");
alert(div);
```